# 301 redirect to different directory on Yahoo Small Business Hosting without .htaccess

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

I have a website hosted with Yahoo Small Business Hosting, and I don't have access to use a *.htaccess* file.

I have around 220 pages in a folder `mysubfolder` (`http://example.com/myfolder/mysubfolder`) and the age of website is around 3 years.

I am planning to move all 220 pages in `mysubfolder` to `myfolder` (one level up). All the pages in `mysubfolder` are indexed.

What is the best way to do this, so that it wouldn't affect my SEO.

Comment: But the best way to do this is using the .htaccess file ;)

Comment: Do you have access to a [Page Redirect Manager](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/store/pageredirects/pageredirects-01.html)? "Using Page Redirect Manager, you can create page-level 301 redirects to direct your site pages to new page locations."

Comment: @w3d: That looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

Another potential option would be to follow the advice listed here - http://www.craniumstorm.com/moving-wordpress-and-yahoo-small-business-hosting/ and create a redirect file in a index.php file. Now, this may or may not work depending on the site you have setup. If its a CMS based site that defaults to looking for the index.php file first, it will work great. If its a bunch of static html files, probably not so much. Either way it wouldn't hurt to give it a try.

```
 <?php
$request = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$request_a = explode("/", $request);
$count = count($request_a) - 1;
$request_res = "";
for ($i = 3; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    $request_res .= "/" . $request_a[$i];
}
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.newdomainfoo.com/bar" . $request_res);
exit();
?>
```

There is also the CSV file upload redirect manager that you could use if you could easily create a list of your current urls, and new urls, however that could be a pain.

The best option would be to migrate away from Yahoo Small Business as it seems rather restricting in many areas. It would be very easy to setup 301 redirects then, but that is outside the purview of your question :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to not impact your SEO, you would need to use a [301 redirect](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en) to let search engines know that the pages have permanently moved to the new directory (see the link for more).

Confirmed with a contact at [Yahoo Small Business Hosting](https://smallbusiness.yahoo.com/webhosting/): You would need to use their [Page Redirect Manager](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-merchant-solutions/SLN19414.html?impressions=true) tool to setup 301 redirect rules as covered [here](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-merchant-solutions/create-redirect-sln19415.html).

Unfortunately, as with URL rewriting using Apache or other webserver, you can't do this programmatically for all URLs using a regex, you would need to set redirect rules for *each* URL.

Since many redirects would be needed however, you can upload your redirect rules as a list in a CSV file, as covered [here](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-merchant-solutions/create-edit-delete-redirects-csv-upload-sln19418.html). Using a spreadsheet, you could just do a find/replace to modify your list of old URLs to change them to the new URLs. You can also change the file extension in addition to the directory.

Of special note covered [here](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-merchant-solutions/create-redirect-sln19415.html) however, you need to *remove* all the files at the old location:

> When creating and editing redirects in Page Redirect Manager, existing
>   site pages may not be redirected while they still exist on your site —
>   the page at the URL you wish to redirect must be deleted first.

You would also need to update any internal links that point to the old directory in your URLs so that they're not broken, and continue to [pass authority](http://www.seomark.co.uk/seo-for-internal-links/). Using the example from the question, search your site and change:

`http://example.com/myfolder/mysubfolder`  to  `http://example.com/myfolder`

Also, try to contact each external site that links to the old URLs to request that they change them to the new URLs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some server side language(PHP, Python, ...) is not difficult get all the URLs finishing on mysubfolder/*** and then redirect to the new folder using Redirect 301

This is a 301 redirect using PHP:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.newdomain.com/newdir/newpage.htm");
exit();
```

If the files are .html and you can't use server side then you should add

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL=http://mysite.com/myfolder/foo.html">
```

to all files on `subfolder` (I recommend download files, then use some text editor with Find & Replace function and upload agin). In any case you should avoid to use Javascript redirect.

Comment: "upload a robots.txt file to subfolder" - A robots.txt file should only ever go in the top level folder. ie `http://mysite.com/robots.txt`. So the disallow line would need to read: `Disallow: /myfolder/mysubfolder/` (if this is to be implemented).

Comment: ...and in any case, using robots.txt to disallow the old URLs would mean that search engines will not see the redirects and won't know that the pages have moved.  Generally that would be a bad idea.

Comment: yes, thats right, 301 redirect is the only way to tell the search engines that the page is moved. otherwise it leads to 404 error.

Comment: @w3d, updated answer, I had no idea that `robots.txt` can be only on the root, I thought it worked because I use it to block subdomains, subfolders at the end right?

Comment: @Tom: It works for subdomains if the `robots.txt` file is in the top level folder for that subdomain. ie. `http://subdomain.mysite.com/robots.txt`. If this is also accessible via the subfolder... `/mysite.com/subdomain/` then this will not work, it will now look for `http://mysite.com/robots.txt`. But, as mentioned by Ilmari Karonen above, blocking these files using `robots.txt` is probably not recommended anyway because you are also blocking the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Canonical Links will do what you want.  [GoogleWebmaster](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394)

1. Copy your existing pages over to your desired directory.
2. Then on the old pages, the ones you DO NOT want to be indexed by Google, add a canonical link pointing to the new location.
3. Find & Replace would make quick work of this change to your 220 pages.

**Example:**
Move this page `http://www.mysite.com/foo/bar/goo.html`
To this location `http://www.mysite.com/foo/goo.html`
Use `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mysite.com/foo/goo.html"/>` in the head of the old page.

Comment: Since the OP is specifically asking about _301 redirects_ for Yahoo Small Business Hosting, they would need to delete all files in the old directory as covered [here](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-merchant-solutions/create-redirect-sln19415.html), and since there would only be one copy of them that would need to be re-indexed, a canonical link is not really necessary because it would just refer to itself.

Comment: That page makes no mention of 301 though and he is concerned about seo.

Comment: Yes it does, see the title. Again, since the old pages would need to be deleted (see the link in my comment), a canonical link is not helpful.

Comment: Are you assuming "redirect" to mean 301? Why not 300, 302, 303, 307?

Comment: Again, the title of the OP's question is asking about _301 redirects_, which would indicate to search engines that they permanently moved as needed to maintain SEO. There are multitudes of questions/answers on this site and elsewhere stating the same.

Comment: Again, nowhere on the page you are linking to does it make mention of 301 redirects. It just says redirects. I maintain that to assuage the OP's SEO concerns he use canonical links until the pages are reindexed by Google. THEN he can remove the old pages and use the Yahoo Redirect Manager.

Comment: Sorry, but you're misreading the OP's questions (see the title of it), and the [Page Redirect Manager](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-merchant-solutions/SLN19414.html?impressions=true) uses 301 redirects. Given the requirements by Yahoo to remove all pages from the old directory, your answer isn't helpful.